# options_from_collection_for_select doesn't save first value in dropdown

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to populate a dropdown menu with values from the database.

I'm using:

```
options_from_collection_for_select
```

The goal is to display a value in the dropdown that will correspond to the user id for that row in the database and when selecting a value the id for that value will be saved.

I'm able to populate the dropdown menu with values and save successfully. The problem is that the first value in the dropdown menu is saved as-

```
"<option value=>"
```

instead of just saving the id (see html source below) . All other values are saved correctly. 
How can I make the first value behave like the others?

This is the code:

```
<% options = options_from_collection_for_select(@landlord, "id", "company_name") %>
<%= f.select :landlord_name, [[:all_val, options], ["Other", "Other"]]
, prompt: "Select...", class: "form-control" %>
```

This is passed from the controller:

```
 @landlord = Landlord.all
```

This is the HTML source:

```
<select name="listing[landlord_name]" id="listing_landlord_name">         
  <option value="">Select...</option>     
  <option value="<option value="9">JOJO</option>
  <option value="10">SHOOKI</option>">all_val</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to populate the select_box with IDs and names from the `@landlord` collection and add an 'Other' option to the end.

The `options_from_collection_for_select` method returns HTML strings to be put inside the select tag, populated with the collection names and IDs, so you have to merge the options differently, in a way like this:

```rb
<% options = options_from_collection_for_select(@landlord, "id", "company_name") %>
<%= f.select :landlord_name, options + options_for_select([["Other", "Other"]]), 
    prompt: "Select...", class: "form-control" %>
```

The code simply appends the collection options string-wise with the output of the `options_for_select`, which is a general helper for select options, also producing strings to be put into the select tag.

Comment: Thanks BoraMa! That's exactly it! it works perfectly